# Justify for $f = u + iv$ analytic at $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Justify:** $f = u + iv$ is analytic at $z_0\implies$ 1) $f$ has derivative of all order at $z_0$; 2) $u, v$ have CONTINUOUS partial derivatives of ALL order at $z_0$.

I'm yet to read taylor/laurent series. Please help me using necessary/sufficient condition for differentiability, idea of analytic function.

Comment: Dear @user146075, it would be very helpful in terms of answering your question if you could (a) write down the definition of "analytic" that you have in mind and (b) be more precise about the parts on which you are stuck. For example, are you familiar with the Cauchy integral formula in complex analysis?

Comment: No. My domain is simply the basic idea of analytic functions.

Comment: Dear @user146075, thanks but what is your definition of "analytic at $z_0$"? Also, if you don't mind me asking, what is the motivation for this question (e.g., curiosity, homework etc.)? I think it is difficult to justify this if you are not familiar with more than the definition of "analytic function" and it might be better to wait until the textbook (if you are self-studying) or course (if you are at university) covers this result.

Comment: A function is said to be ANALYTIC at a point if it’s differentiable everywhere in SOME nbd of that point.

Comment: OK, if you can prove that "$f$ analytic $\implies$ $f'$ analytic", then (1) follows. (2) also follows if you know that the coordinates of $f'$ can be written in terms of the first partial derivatives of the coordinates of $f$ ($u$ and $v$).

Comment: Sorry. I need further help.

Comment: @user146075: that is not equivalent to the standard definition of an [analytic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function), which has to do with being expressible as a power series. This definition does not imply the properties you want to show. Is that the definition you were given?

Comment: @robjohn, isn't it true that if a complex-valued function $f$ is differentiable (in the complex sense) at every point on an open subset of the complex plane, then $f$ is analytic (in that it is locally expressible as a power series), and vice-versa. Or, am I confused?

Comment: @user146075: I am surprised that you are being asked about complex analytic functions when you have not yet studied Taylor series. Proving that simply having a *complex* derivative at all points in an open set implies derivatives of all orders is usually done after proving [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) and [Cauchy's Integral Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula).

Comment: @AmiteshDatta: it is true that if $f$ has a complex derivative at every point of an open set then it is analytic, but that is not usually used as the definition of analytic. That is usually the definition of holomorphic.

Comment: @user146075: in light of my reply to Amitesh Datta, I misspoke when I said that your definition does not imply the properties you want to show. I was not certain what you meant by "$f$ is differentiable", but I guess that can be inferred from context.

Comment: Dear @robjohn, but you wrote "that is not equivalent to the standard definition of analytic function ...". In my experience with complex analysis, "holomorphic" and "analytic" are used interchangeably precisely because they are equivalent (which seems to contradict your claim). You also wrote "this definition does not imply the properties you want to show" - this seems false to me as the two definitions are equivalent, and analyticity implies both of those properties. Thus, unless I am mistaken, I think that particular comment of yours is false - do you agree or disagree?

Comment: @AmiteshDatta: a function which is holomorphic (has a complex derivative at every point) can be proven to be analytic (expressible as a power series), and vice versa; however, I would not say that the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: In any case, I do find this question somewhat unusual as it essentially constitutes a major theorem in complex analysis which should be covered in any textbook or university course on the subject. I wondered if this was assigned as homework but that would also be unusual. So, I am not entirely sure about the motivation for this question. I would recommend to @user146075 to learn the Cauchy integral formula from which this result is essentially immediate (the Cauchy integral formula also captures the real reason why this result is true).

Comment: Dear @robjohn, ok maybe we have different definitions of "equivalent" (I am thinking in terms of "logically equivalent"). In any case, though, it seems to me the case that either definition implies both of the properties the OP would like to show.

Comment: @AmiteshDatta: yes, in [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771075/justify-for-f-u-iv-analytic-at-z-0?noredirect=1#comment1600941_771075), I retracted some of what I had said. Since it was just before your reply, I don't know if you noticed.

Comment: @robjohn OK, I saw it now; thanks very much.